# Typescript node_modules packages versions conflict

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, draftjs

In our project, we use the **Immutable** version `4.0.0-rc.12`, after install `@types/draft-js`, the new type error arises, which doesn't exist before. I realize that is related that the `@types/draft-js` use different version od immutable  `immutable": "~3.7.4` so it looks like the whole project start use types from Immutable version  `~3.7.4` instead of `4.0.0-rc.12`.

I am really stuck on this, I didn't found any information about why this happens, or how to handle that.

I appreciate any help, or information where should I look and read about that.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding resolutions block to your package.json

```
"resolutions": {
   "@types/draft-js/immutable": "4.0.0-rc.12"
},
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good idea, I am going to try, that.

Comment: Hm not working, it breaks an app, I suppose that even this is changed the dependency just for `"@types/draft-js`, it also tells typescript to compile draft-js with `4.0.0-rc.12`